# Android application is not connecting to web API which is deployed on live server on local environment its working fine

Tags: android, android-studio, iis, asp.net-web-api, okhttp

I am facing this issue but did not get the solution yet.
Application base on Web API and its working fine on local environment but when we deployed our web services on a live server, some time android application fetching data perfectly but often it returns this error

> java.net.socketTimeoutException: Failed to connect to/my_url(port 8081) after 10000

I have deployed on IIS.

Comment: Learn how to add retry mechanism. No one guarantees an error-free internet environment (other than your local environment), so adapt to that.

Comment: The Internet and server are working properly because I have checked it from browser it works fine but from the android application, it's not.

Comment: This could be caused by a proxy. Are the proxy settings on the browser and on the android device identical?

Comment: Dear @J.Gerbershagen Thank you so much for your response. Could you elaborate further I didn't get it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a client.
I was creating a client in each call. when multiple service call at a time it blocks the network operation.